# Restrict google maps searchbox to country Level

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

for search. We can bound searchbox results to city, state which works fine. However bounding searchbox to country doesn't seem to be working. It's suggesting locations that's not prior to specific country.

I am searching kfc in Pakistan using searchbox, but its giving me the same business name only in India.

I am unable to understand reason.

Any kind of help/suggestion/information would be appreciated. Thanks.
Here is the fiddle

jsfiddle.net/2caxzLxm/2

Answer (score 0):

Use `setBounds` as in example you used

```
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
```

And adjust your zoom level to 6 then only results to

> // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpzvnhff/) demo

Comment: I need the same case with any other country. Same zoom level will not be feasible. Moreover I have a pull down of countries, on selecting any,
'searchBox.setBounds(country.viewport);'
is called.

Comment: base on country size you have to adjust zoom so that it is in  current map's viewport. then only correct search result will come within specified location

Comment: How can I set zoom level for any other country? Do we have any other technique for doing so?

Comment: this based on you how you adjust the zoom level while initializing `var map=new google.maps.Map(...)`